# How to change background color for only one bootstrap popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have applied background color for popover.

Problem is, how to change background color for only popover using css.

```
a.top > .popover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

[My code is add here](https://jsfiddle.net/xc63nskx/3/)

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: change css only target ".popover"

Comment: your fiddle not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom class for `a`

HTML

```
<a data-content="Content" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" title="" href="#" data-original-title="Header" class="test">top</a>
```

CSS

```
.test + .popover.top {
   background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: Here background-color will affect for all top positioned popovers. But, I need to change for only one

Comment: no need to add custom class .. just check the below code it's works fine

Answer (score -1):

THIS WORKS WELL

```
.popover.fade.top.in{background-color:white;} 
.popover.fade.bottom.in{background-color:red;} 
.popover.fade.left.in{background-color:yellow;} 
.popover.fade.right.in{background-color:green;}
```

CHANGE THE COLOR YOU WANT TO CHANGE.

[jsfiddle demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1onkeamb/show/#)

Comment: Here background-color will affect for all top positioned popovers. But,  need to change for only one

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Add a class to that one popover element and focus it by using that class in your CSS (make sure you add it after the standard styles being used for all the other popovers).
2. Style only this one popover by counting. If you do know it's position relative to the other popovers in the DOM you could select it with the `nth-of-type` or the `nth-child` selector. Here is a wonderful article explaining the whole concept: http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css